# Service causing Remote Desktop to become unresponsive

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm testing a service on a server (win 2008 r2) that we have to remote desktop in to, but starting the service causes remote desktop to become largely unresponsive. It will still take input, but seems to only register one action a minute and only update the display once a minute.

Obviously the problem is with the service (which causes no such problems on my local machine), but I cannot properly debug the issue when remote desktop is so slow.

If I had to guess I would say that the service is using up too much processing power on the server and therefore remote desktop cannot run efficiently. If this is the case is there a way to ringfence some processing power for remote desktop so that it doesn't become so slow?

Comment: Is that service using any network resources?

Comment: I would recommend running the *System Performance* [Data Collector Set](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722312.aspx) or creating your own collector set that records the relevant information you need in Windows' [Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771692.aspx)

Comment: @week - It's a WCF service hosted in a windows service that uses a netTcpBinding. From the little experimenting i've been able to do it's the thread that checks a Message Queue that makes the difference (commenting it out stops the issue)

Comment: @Septih in that case I would post the code that is checking your message queue over at stackoverflow. Depending on how you are checking you could be pegging a CPU core at 100%. If your system only has one CPU or there are more than one than one of these queues it could easy tax out your system. [Edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/667861/edit) to include the code then flag it for a moderator and they can move the question over. We really need to see that code to help you solve your problem (and it is likely a easy fix too)

Comment: As ad-hoc solution I would try to set higher priority to `svchost.exe` with `termsrv.dll`. You can use Sysinternals utility [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to identify.

Comment: There are lots of tools to profile the performance of said your service.  Have you used those tools